# iText7 - Add text to the bottom of existing pdf

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext7

I need to add some text content to the bottom of an existing .pdf document with iText. I have a working method, but the new content is displayed in the top-left corner, overlapping the existing content:

```
public PdfDocument GetDocumentWithAppendedContent(string path, string content)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new PdfWriter(stream);
        writer.SetCloseStream(false); // so I can reuse stream to create a readonly document later

        var pdfResult = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(path), writer);
        var document = new Document(pdfResult);

        var div = new Div().SetMargin(0).SetPadding(0).SetKeepTogether(true);
        div.Add(new Paragraph(content));
        document.Add(div);
        
        document.Close();
        pdfResult.Close();

        stream.Position = 0;
        return new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(stream)); // return a readonly version
    }
```

How to "move" the `content` at the bottom of the last page, instead of the beginning of the first? I am new to iText and, surprisingly, can't find a solution online.

Comment: PDFs generally don't contain a marker denoting the position where to continue adding new content. Of course one can simply determine the bounding box of everything on the page and start underneath. Considering, though, that pages may have some footer or some background graphics, this simply approach may not be what you want...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the code like this.

```
   PdfPage     page   = doc.GetPage(doc.GetNumberOfPages());
    //Create canvas fro the last page
    Canvas      canvas = new Canvas(page, page.GetPageSize());
    //Set fixed position to put the div at the left bottom  corner of the canvas
    div.SetFixedPosition(0, 0, page.getPageSize().getWidth());
    canvas.Add(p);
    doc.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that works perfectly if the last page isn't full to the end. But is there a way to add the Div to the existing hierarchy, so it would flow with the rest of the document?

Comment: @dzenesiz did you find the solution.
Please share if yes.